# Jenkins, MSBuild, and NUnit: error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, continuous-integration, nunit

I'm trying run builds from Jenkins where MSBuild runs NUnit tests, but MSBuild keeps complaining of multiple projects being passed:

> MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified. Switch:
>   C:\Users[User]\Desktop[Me]\Programming\My_Desktop_Apps\SimpleCalcApp\SimpleCalcTests\bin\Debug\SimpleCalcTests.dll

From what I understand, there's a space in the argument list that fools MSBuild into thinking there are multiple projects. Here are the Command Line Arguments:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit.org\nunit-console\nunit3-console.exe C:\Users\NGalaxy\Desktop\Nate\Programming\My_Desktop_Apps\SimpleCalcApp\SimpleCalcTests\bin\Debug\SimpleCalcTests.dll /xml=nunit-result.xml

I've tried using double-quotes and backslashes dozens of times now, but to no avail. I know this error code from MSBuild is posted numerous times, but everyone else is running there builds from the cmd. (I can't seem to find a straight answer on how you run NUnit tests through MSBuild from the cmd either.)

I'm following a tutorial series by [Andy French about setting up Jenkins, Git, and MSBuild](http://www.andyfrench.info/2015/03/getting-started-with-jenkins-git-and.html)

It's the clearest tutorial I could find on the topic. I've been at this for 7+ hours so if I'm missing something, let me know!
However, if you'd like to suggest alternatives to NUnit or Jenkins, explain installs/configs thoroughly or link to extensive documentation, please. XD

Comment: The Program Files directory has a space. Put double quotes around the entire path and name of the console runner.